# having this Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am trying to upload my flutter app on the play store but it showing errors. Firstly I had stored the key file on this default location with this default name "c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-Keystore.jks". right now my Keystore file is in this default location but copied it to the android/app folder of the project.
But still getting the errors while releasing tried everything looked everywhere now I am stuck help me out, please.

Attaching the screenshot of the error & key.properties file.

[the error on the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16QZm.png)

[keystore properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9STHV.png)

I've used the android studio terminal with "Run command using IDE checked" & generated the key from android studio.

Comment: Did you forgot your alias? By the way first link does not work.

Comment: @CidQu I've edited please check

Comment: Try to rename it as `storeFile=projectkey.jks` and I hope you have the correct alias for the keystore file. If you don't know the correct alias, you may need to create new keystore file.

Comment: @CidQu I've already created Keystore file 4-5 times saving it on different locations & getting the same error

Comment: Acording to your original post you saved your keystore file in c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-Keystore.jks". You need to copy your keystore to "android/app" in your flutter project. Then use "storeFile=projectkey.jks" to use it.

Comment: Like in the store file: I should use this "c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-Keystore.jks" or just storeFile="upload-Keystore.jks" ??

Comment: I'm posting as an answer what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add your keystore file in `flutterproject/android/app`
2. Edit your gradle file as fallow;

   signingConfigs {
   release {
   keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
   keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
   storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
   storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
   }
   }
3. Then edit your keystore.properties like this:

   storePassword=pass
   keyPassword=pass
   keyAlias=key
   storeFile=keystore.jks

If your alias and passwords are right, this should work.